# How to prove: $\left|\int_0^1 f(x) d x\right| \leq \frac{1-a}{2} \max _{0<x<1}\left|f^{\prime}(x)\right|$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, inequality, definite-integrals

I found this question on the 1998 Roorkee Paper during my crazy hunt for mind-blowing calculus questions.

> Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous
> function, differentiable on $(0,1)$ such that $\int_0^{a}
>  f(x) dx=0$ for some $a \in(0,1)$, then
>
> (1) $\left|\int_0^1 f(x) d x\right| \leq \frac{1-a}{2} \max
>  _{0<x<1}\left|f^{\prime}(x)\right|$
>
> (2) $\left|\int_0^1 f(x)dx\right|>\frac{1-\mathrm{a}}{2} \max_{0<x<1}\left|f'(x)\right|$
>
> (3) $\left|\int_0^1 f(x) d x\right|=\frac{1-a}{2} \max_{0<x<1}\left|f^{\prime}(x)\right|$ for some function $f(x)$
>
> (4) none of the other options is correct

And ofcourse I have no idea on how to solve this.
However on carefully reading the options and noticing $\frac{1-a}{2}$, I thought of making a connection with the concept of '[Definite Integral as Limit of Sum](https://cdn1.byjus.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Definite-integral-formula-3.png)' where $\frac{b-a}{h}$ could  be $\frac{1-a}{2}$ here.

Then I also believe there is an involvement of Lagranges Mean Value Theorem somewhere as the questions says continuous and differentiable.

I presented my observations to my teacher and he gave me a hint: "Put $x=at$ and change limits accordingly and try to apply your concepts."

Could someone kindly help me with this one.

Comment: Can you find counter-examples to two of the possible answers?

Comment: @Henry Didnt get you

Comment: I suggest you play around with simple functions $f$, such as $f(x) = x - c$ for various constants $c$. Can you choose $c$ so that (1) is false, and or so that (2) is false, or so that (3) is true? Note that the value $a$ in the problem statement will be different for each $c$. If this doesn't work, move on to somewhat more complicated functions. Even if it doesn't solve your problem by itself, it will give you some idea of what is going on here, which can help you move forward.

Comment: I took that Roorkee entrance exam in 1998, but I am not able to recall this question at all. The integral $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx$ can be simply replaced by $\int_a^1 f(x) \, dx$ which equals $(1-a)f(c)$ for some $c\in(a, 1)$ and then we need to compare values of $f(c) $ with that of $2f'(x)$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I  havn't seen the Roorkee 1998 paper officially, but my Indian friend gave me a book which contained topic wise questions till 2001...so it was written 1998 beside the question. Anyways perhaps the book might have misprinted

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you Mr. Singh. Could you kindly elaborate on what basis you replaced that integral. I'm a bit recent into calculus and don't have a firm grasp on it. I would be grateful if you could elaborate more for me.

Comment: What is option (3) actually saying? Wouldn't $f(x)=0$ trivially work? I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: @Paramanand, your replacement is too loose. If $f(x)=x$ then the integral is $1/2$, but  you’d get an upper bound of $1 \cdot 1$.

Comment: Side note: it's not like you're doing anything wrong, but I feel like the questions you've been asking on this site are too advanced for your current level. It's like if a student, who's learning what sums are and what $\sum$ means, asks questions that involve Taylor series. I've been noticing that whenever you get an answer, you still have questions about fundamental concepts important to your OPs. Of course, curiosity is good and I don't know where your experience lies in math, but I suggest reading a math textbook about the basics of proofs to gain some self-sufficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M=max_{0<x<1} |f’(x)|$.

This is tricky. Let me give some intuition first. It’s best to think of $M$ as constant and then trying to maximize the integral. We know that after $a$, $f$ is linearly bounded, so we need to try to get a good upper bound for $f(a)$. Since the derivative of $f$ is bounded, we need to try to show that $f$ itself can’t be too large. One way to relate an integral with derivatives is integration by parts which happens to work out well. On to the proof.

Applying integration by parts to $x f(x)$ gives:

$$af(a)=\int^a_0 f(x)dx + \int^a_0 xf’(x)dx$$
$$af(a)=\int^a_0 xf’(x)dx$$
$$|af(a)|\leq \int^a_0 x|f’(x)| dx \leq M \int^a_0 xdx=M a^2/2$$

Thus, $|f(a)|\leq M a/2$, so for $a<x$, $|f(x)|\leq |f(a)|+|f(x)-f(a)| \leq Ma/2+M(x-a)$.

$$|\int_0^1 f(x)dx|= |\int^1_a f(x)dx|$$
$$ \leq \int^1_a |f(x)|dx$$
$$ \leq \int^1_a (Ma/2+M(x-a))dx$$
$$ \leq M\int^1_a (x-a/2)dx$$
$$ \leq M(1^2/2-a^2/2-a/2(1-a))dx$$
$$ \leq M(1-a)/2$$

Thus, the answer is (1).

Note that if you haven’t gotten around to integration by parts yet, there’s another way to get a bound on $f(a)$. Consider $f(x)-M(x-a/2)$. It has nonpositive slope and integrates to $0$ from $0$ to $a$. By the mean value theorem, it must be 0 at some point and since it has nonpositive slope, we get that it’s final value is negative, so $f(a) - M(a-a/2) \leq 0$, so $f(a) \leq Ma/2$. The same argument on $-f(x)$ gives that $-f(a) \leq Ma/2$, so $|f(a)|\leq Ma/2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^afdx=0=xf\bigg|_0^a-\int_0^a xf'dx=af(a)-\int_0^a xf'dx$$

Let $\displaystyle m=\max_{x\in(0,1)} |f'|$, we get

$$|af(a)|=\left|\int_0^a xf'dx\right|\le m \left|\int_0^a xdx\right|=m\frac12a^2\Longrightarrow |f(a)|\le \frac a2m$$

hence

$$\begin{align}\left|\int_0^1 fdx\right|&=\left|\int_a^1 fdx\right|=\left|\int_a^1 f(a)+f'(\xi )(x-a)dx\right|\\
\\
&\le\left|\int_a^1 f(a)dx\right|+\left|\int_a^1f'(\xi )(x-a)dx\right|\\
\\
&\le\left|\int_a^1 f(a)dx\right|+m\left|\int_a^1(x-a)dx\right|\\
\\
&= (1-a)|f(a)|+m\cdot\frac12(1-a)^2\\
\\
&\le (1-a)\frac a2m+m\cdot\frac12(1-a)^2\\
\\
&=\frac{1-a}2m\\
\\
&=\frac{1-a}2\max_{x\in(0,1)} |f'|\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

The conclusion of $(1)$ and $(3)$ follow straightforward from the Taylor formula applied to the antiderivative $F(x)=\int\limits_0^xf(t)\,dt.$ We have $F(1)=\int\limits_0^1f(t)\,dt$ and
$$M:=\max_{0\le x\le 1} |f'(x)|=\max_{0\le x\le 1} |F''(x)|$$
By assumption $F(a)=0$ for some $0<a<1.$ The Taylor formulas at $0$ and $1,$ with respect to $a,$ yield
$$
0=F(0)=F'(a)(-a)+{F''(\eta_1)\over 2}a^2\\
F(1)=F'(a)(1-a)+{F''(\eta_2)\over 2}(1-a)^2$$ for some $0<\eta_1<a<\eta_2<1.$
Calculating $F'(a)$ from the first equality and substituting it into the second one gives
$$F(1)={F''(\eta_1)\over 2}a(1-a)+{F''(\eta_2)\over 2}(1-a)^2\quad (*)$$ Therefore
$$|F(1)|\le {M\over 2}a(1-a)+{M\over 2}{(1-a)^2} ={M(1-a)\over 2}\quad (**)$$
In view of $(*),$ the equality in $(**)$ occurs when $F''=f'$ is constant, i.e. $f$ is an affine   function vanishing at $x_0,$ $0<x_0<{1\over 2},$ for example $f(x)=3x-1.$ Clearly it also holds for the trivial case $f\equiv 0.$